# PHP arrays, getting multi-dimensional data from for reach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've looked on stackoverflow for the answer, but no one explains it properly.

I have a while loop that works:

```
info = array();
while($get_info= mysql_fetch_array($info_result)){
    $info['team_id'] = $get_info['team_id'];
    $info['team_points'] = $get_info['team_points'];
}
```

And when I print out the array:

> Array ( [team_id] => 26 [team_points] => 100 )

But my foreach returns an invalid argument.

```
foreach ($info as $info_mation ){
    echo $info_mation['team_id'];
    echo $info_mation['team_points'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

I've tried many different ways but nothing works.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean `print_r($info)` works, while `foreach ($info as $info_mation)` doesn't??

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in fetching data from DB. Modify your `while` loop like this:

```
info = array();
while($get_info = mysql_fetch_array($info_result)){
    $temp_info = array();
    $temp_info['team_id'] = $get_info['team_id'];
    $temp_info['team_points'] = $get_info['team_points'];

    $info[] = $temp_info;
}
```

Now your `foreach` loop should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more explanation, if what you've seen so far doesn't make sense. When you do this:

```
$info = array();
while($get_info = mysql_fetch_array($info_result)) {
    $info['team_id'] = $get_info['team_id'];
    $info['team_points'] = $get_info['team_points'];
}
```

You are overwriting `$info` with each iteration of the while loop. So at the end of your loop, `$info` will only contain the last row of your query result.
This explains the result you see:

> Array ( [team_id] => 26 [team_points] => 100 )

So when you iterate this array with

```
foreach ($info as $info_mation ){
    echo $info_mation['team_id'];
    echo $info_mation['team_points'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

`$info_mation` will contain 26, and then 100, which are indeed invalid for `foreach`.

You need to create a multidimensional array rather than a one-dimensional array. You can do that by modifying your `while` loop slightly:

```
while($get_info= mysql_fetch_array($info_result)) {
    $info[] = $get_info;
}
```

Doing it this way adds a new array element to the `$info` array with each iteration, rather than overwriting the same two elements repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

this is your code:

```
info = array();
while($get_info= mysql_fetch_array($info_result)){
   $info['team_id'] = $get_info['team_id'];
   $info['team_points'] = $get_info['team_points'];
}
```

change it to this:

```
$info = array();
while($get_info= mysql_fetch_array($info_result)){
   $info[] = array(
       'team_id' => $get_info['team_id'],
       'team_points' => $get_info['team_points']
   );
}
```

so, your $info variable contains all the array from the sql result you made.

```
foreach($info as $inf) {
   echo $inf['team_id'];   
   echo $inf['team_points'];
   echo '<br>';
}
```

and we're done! :)